# Rxjs Interval switchMap once http call finishes

Tags: rxjs

We have a timer that ticks e.g. every 2 seconds, whenever there is a tick we make a http call. The response time varies, it might be 100 ms but it might be 4 seconds. The catch is that we only make a new http call if the previous one completed. So we have 2 cases:

#1 If each http call takes 10sec we should be only sending a request every 10 seconds.
#2 If each http call takes 100ms we should be sending a request every 2 seconds.

What is also difficult in this scenario is that the `getHttp` call relies on value from the `interval$` stream.

The best solution I came up so far is this:

```js
import { of, interval, timer, combineLatest, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const interval$ = interval(2000).pipe(tap(console.log))

const readyForNext$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);

// Mocked http request that (in reality) uses the value from interval$
function getHttp(value) {
  return of(value).pipe(
    tap(() => readyForNext$.next(false)),
    tap(() => console.log('getHttp: starting ')),
    switchMap(() => timer(3000)),
    tap(() => console.log('getHttp: resolve')),
    map(() => 'hello'),
  );
}

const anotherMockedStream$ = of(1) // In real code we have 2 streams in combineLatest

combineLatest([interval$, readyForNext$])
  .pipe(
    filter(([_, isReady]) => isReady),
    switchMap(([value]) => {
      return combineLatest([getHttp(value), anotherMockedStream$])
    }),
    tap(() => readyForNext$.next(true)),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Playground: https://playcode.io/1023332
Alternative playground: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jdjjsc?file=index.ts

There are however two problem with this solution, it only works for case #1 and it is not very elegant (the use of readyForNext$). How to improve this code?

Comment: So you want to set a delay for the next call based on response time from the previous request (or at least 2s)?

Comment: No, the response body from the request is irrelevant. We have an independent timer that triggers the request but only if there is no other request (of that type) currently pending.

Comment: Its sounds like `exhaustMap()` to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @martin for pointing to `exhaustMap`, this is the correct operator for the operation, it seems to me that it is similar to `switchMap` but only does the switch once the steam is completed (or the emitted value reaches the subscription).

The working code looks as follows:

```js
import { of, interval, timer, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, tap, exhaustMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const interval$ = interval(2000).pipe(tap(console.log))

// Mocked http request that (in reality) uses the value from interval$
function getHttp(value) {
  return of(value).pipe(
    tap(() => console.log('getHttp: starting ')),
    switchMap(() => timer(3000)),
    tap(() => console.log('getHttp: resolve')),
    map(() => 'hello'),
  );
}

const anotherMockedStream$ = of(1)

interval$.pipe(
  exhaustMap(val => {
    return combineLatest([getHttp(val), anotherMockedStream$])
  })
).subscribe(console.log);
```

With it I was able to remove the unnecessary `readyForNext$` and it also works for both case #1 and case #2, i.e. if `timer`'s value is lower or higher than `interval`.

Comment: For your use case this is indeed better than mine, with the slight caveat, that this will always wait for `interval$`, e.g. if the request takes 3 seconds it will wait one more second for the next emission of `interval$`. Yep, but it looks good otherwise :)

Comment: That's exactly what we want to achieve :) This is done for data refreshing so we don't want to spam the API with too frequent requests.